# How do I make web inspector work iOS 13.3.1 and Safari 13.0.5 or Safari Technology Preview 13.2?

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari, web-inspector, safari-web-inspector

I am connecting my iPhone 5 SE with an Apple OEM lighting-to-thunderbolt cable. I have the latest version of macOS (10.15.3) installed.

I have made sure that the Web Inspector setting in Settings > Safari > Advanced is turned on.

On both Safari and Safari Technology Preview I have enabled the Develop menu. My device does not show up in either.

I tried removing trusted devices from my iPhone by resetting my location and privacy in General > Reset. I then re-added my macOS system as a trusted device. This did not help either.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried a different cable or USB port? Are you using unusual VPN or network settings on the devices? Can the devices connect with WiFi instead of a cable? https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/wi-fi-syncing-mchlada1d602/10.15/mac/10.15

Comment: I will try to get a different cable and try WiFi connection, thanks! No VPN or weird network settings that I am aware of.

Comment: After turning on WiFi sync on iTunes and enabling connection via network in Xcode for debugging (Window > Devices and Simulators), my phone is appearing in Safari Develop. However, only when the cable is plugged-in! If you want to update your answer to mention trying setting up WiFi sync I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: After changing locations and making another attempt, I was able to get the web inspector working even wirelessly. I suspect that network settings in the old network were interfering.

Answer (score 1):

I am using OSX 10.15.3, (non-preview) Safari 13.0.5 and an iPhone 7 (A1660) running iOS 13.3. I plugged the phone into the Mac for the first time and trusted the computer. The Web Inspector and Remote Automation settings are available on the phone. Desktop Safari is able to find the phone in its Develop tab. It is possible to debug web pages or progressive web apps saved to the home screen, when one or both of Web Inspect and Remote Automation are enabled on the phone. Even if the debugger is not enabled, desktop Safari still knows the phone is there but shows No Inspectable Applications.

Try setting up WiFi sync for the phone, and connecting it with the cable.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if perhaps the iPhone 5 SE is too old for web inspector to work?

Answer (score 0):

I am using this tool-  Safari Technology Preview to debug my iphone on mac.

Download link- https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/